# Do parent threads wait for child threads to exit before they also exit in servlet containers?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

**Question:**
If you spawn new threads inside a servlet/controller and the main thread handling that controller has completed, will the controller thread block until all of its child threads have returned before it also returns?

**Background**:
I have some code running in separate threads spawned from inside a controller but the thread handling the controller doesn't seem to return independently; theres a long delay of the exact length of the child thread's process time. It appears to be waiting for the child threads to finish before it exits. Is this normal?

**Question Simplified:** I know the child thread(s) will run without blocking the parent when the parent is running but what happens when the parent finishes its tasks?

Comment: Threads are completely independent in Java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is that always the case for servlet containers though? Its definitely waiting on the children before returning. The time delay is the same as that of its threads

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil It is true for all threads in Java, period. There is no way a servlet container could change these semantics, even if it wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly call *join* on Thread, to wait for it to finish, otherwise it just runs in background, not affecting your parent Thread. So you controller should not block, until your child Thread return.

Although, you might have some configurations, in your container, depending on your container, which could lead to this, but I seriously doubt that.

Comment: Thanks. I meant the logic in each child would run sequentially without blocking the parent or any other thread but I just deleted that line because I did a bad job explaining myself there so you can edit your response if you like...I'll poke around my tomcat configuration in the mean time. Thanks.

Comment: Working on it. It may indeed be a config issue. I will return with an update and if not solved I'll post my code. Thanks.

Comment: I think its related to something else so I'll post my code  in another question since this answers my question with regard to the JVM. Thanks.